# Show that the following four conditions of a linear map are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\theta:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map, where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional. Prove the following four conditions are equivalent:

1. $\theta$ is injective (or one-to-one)
2. $\theta$ is onto
3. $\text{ker } \theta = \{0_v\}$
4. $\theta$ has an inverse i.e. there exists a $\tau:W \rightarrow V$ such that $\tau\theta= \text{identity map}$

So far I have that, for 1.) $\implies$ 2.,

Let $x \in \text{ker }\theta$ then $\theta(x) = 0$, but as $\theta$ is a linear map we have that $\theta(0_v)=0_w=\theta(x)$
and now, since $\theta$ is $1-1$, we have that $0_v = x$ and hence $\text{ker } = \{0_v\}$

So far, in the next step, I have tried to use the rank nullity theorem,

\begin{align}
\text{dim }V=\text{rank }\theta+\text{null }\theta
\end{align}

and tried to get that $\text{dim }V=\text{rank }\theta$.

Some texts that I have read say that when $\text{ker }\theta = \{0_v\}$ then $\text{null }\theta = 0$ but I think it should be 1? Could someone please explain this to me.

Comment: $\text{null } \theta := \dim \ker \theta$, so if $\ker \theta = \{0_v\}$ then $\text{null } \theta = \dim \{0_v\} = 0$.

Comment: Note that you need $\dim V=\dim W$.

Comment: As  Diego mentioned, if $\;\dim V\neq \dim W\;$ then the conditions aren't equivalent. Counterexample $$T:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2\;,\;\;Tx=\binom x0\;$$ This is injective but obviously not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

1 iff 3:If $\theta$ is inyective then suppose $x\in \ker \theta$, $\theta (x) = 0$ but $\theta (0) = 0$ and $\theta $is inyective, hence $x= 0$.
suppose $\ker \theta = \{0\}$, if $\theta x = \theta y \implies \theta (x-y) = 0 \implies x-y \in \ker \theta \implies x - y= 0$ then $\theta $ is inyective

1 implies 4: Suppose $\theta$ ins inyective, let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ a basis of $V$, then inyectivity implies that $\theta(v_1),\dots,\theta(v_n)$ is a linearly independent subset of $W$. We can extend this to a basis $\{w_1:=\theta(v_1),\dots,w_n:=\theta(v_n), w_{n+1}, \dots, w_m\}$ of $W$, define a linear operator $\tau$ as follows
$$\tau(w_i) = v_i \qquad\text{for } \quad i=1,\dots,n$$
$$\tau(w_i) = 0 \qquad \text{for}\quad i=n+1,\dots,m$$
then if we extend $\tau$  by linearity we get $\tau \circ \theta = id_V$

4 implies 3: suppose $x\in \ker \theta$, then $\theta x = 0 \implies x = \tau \circ \theta (x) = 0$

as was mentioned earlier $\theta$ won't be onto if $\dim W \not= \dim V$